# how to store gzipped files on server with .htaccess setting (apache 2)?

Tags: apache, gzip

i'm looking for a rule to set on my .htaccess for store a gzipped file on the server when it will gzipped from the server. If is it possible i can save the cpu from always gzip the same files and the server could simply send the gzipped file instead of gzipped it "on the fly".

This is my .htaccess configuration

```
    # BEGIN Compress text files
    <ifModule mod_deflate.c>
      <filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      </filesMatch>
    </ifModule>
    # END Compress text files

    # BEGIN Expire headers
    <ifModule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
    </ifModule>
    # END Expire headers

    # BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
      <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
      </filesMatch>
    </ifModule>
    # END Cache-Control Headers

    # BEGIN Turn ETags Off
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset ETag
    </ifModule>
    FileETag None
    # END Turn ETags Off

    # BEGIN Remove Last-Modified Header
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset Last-Modified
    </ifModule>
    # END Remove Last-Modified Header
```

thanks